If $\mu_a = \nu_a$ for all $a \in [0, 1]$, then $\mu = \nu$
Let $X$ be any nonempty set, let $\mu, \nu \colon X \longrightarrow [0, 1]$ be functions such that, for all $a \in [0, 1]$, we have
$$
\mu_a = \nu_a,
$$
where
$$
\mu_a := \{ x \in X \vert \mu(x) \geq a \},
$$
and $\nu_a$ is similarly defined. [These sets are called the $a$-cuts of $a$-level sets of $\mu$ and $\nu$, respectively.]
How to show from this that $\mu = \nu$?
My Attempt:
If $\mu \neq \mu$, then we must have $\mu \left( x_0 \right) \neq \nu \left( x_0 \right)$ for at least one point $x_0 \in X$. We assume without loss of generality that $\mu \left( x_0 \right) < \nu \left( x_0 \right)$. Let us choose a number $a$ between $\mu \left( x_0 \right)$ and $\nu \left( x_0 \right)$. That is, let $a$ be any number such that
$$
\mu \left( x_0 \right) < a < \nu \left( x_0 \right).
$$
Such an $a$ of course is in $[0, 1]$ because both $\mu \left( x_0 \right)$ and $\nu \left( x_0 \right)$ are. Then we find that $x_0 \in \nu_a$ but $x_0 \not\in \mu_a$, which contradicts our assumption that $\mu_a = \nu_a$. So $\mu(x) = \nu(x)$ fpr all $x \in [0, 1]$. Hence $\mu = \nu$, as required.
Is this proof satisfactory enough? Or, is it lacking in clarity or accuracy?

Your proof by contradiction is ok. A direct and shorter proof consists in using:
$$\mu(x)=a\iff(x\in\mu_a\land\forall b>a\quad x\notin\mu_b).$$
